# Problem with jquery animation

Tags: jquery, animation

You can view the page here (and see the problem) http://rssreaderbg.net/pubsubbub/example/cssexam/index.php
Click on one of the icons(the planet,cloud etc.).After the animation ,double click again on the icon and repeat the whole action again.The animation is buggy.How can I fix that?
Here's a video:
http://www.screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cXnf2OlP2

The problem is that I don't know how to restore the original icons position on double click.

**Edit**:

Now I have another problem.This time the icon has some delay when the event on double click is triggered.
You can see it from here http://www.screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cXnhXElRz
How can I remove that delay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the new animation on double click I put `$("#"+icon).stop(true);` and the delay has gone.

Answer (score 0):

Mark the .iconsss with some sort of HTML attribute to tell the original position.

On the first click have all but the icon clicked on disappear, and the clicked icon animate to the "selected" position. It looks like you basically have that down.

Then on the double click show all icons and reset all of them to the original positions marked with the attr.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var icon = '';

$(".iconsss").click(function() {

    if(icon != $(this).attr("id"))
    {
       icon = $(this).attr("id");
        // do everything else;
    }
});
```